# Проблема с методом subprocess.Popen после компиляции pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, subprocess

### Вопрос

Суть скрипта (gui_3.py) в том, что она запускает форму tkinter с полями и кнопкой. По нажатию на кнопку происходит запуск других скриптов python, вот пример одного:
`process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "first.py"])`
При запуске без компиляции все работает корректно, Popen отрабатывает как надо, однако после компиляции (лог ниже) вместо того, чтобы открывать скрипты, которые я указал, он начинает просто запускать тот же самый скрипт gui_3.py. **Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как мне сделать так, чтобы скрипты все таки запускались как надо?**

### Лог компиляции pyinstaller:

```html
C:\123\program>pyinstaller gui_3.py
291 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
291 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
291 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
308 INFO: wrote C:\123\program\gui_3.spec
308 INFO: UPX is not available.
308 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\123\\program', 'C:\\123\\program']
399 INFO: checking Analysis
399 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
399 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
399 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
417 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
454 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5399 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5399 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib'
11073 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
11631 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
11631 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe
11771 INFO: Analyzing C:\123\program\gui_3.py
18459 INFO: Processing module hooks...
18459 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18477 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18477 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18477 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18621 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18640 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18731 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18731 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18748 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18929 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18929 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18929 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19053 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19359 INFO: checking Tree
19359 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
19376 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
19592 INFO: checking Tree
19592 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
19592 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
19754 INFO: checking Tree
19754 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
19754 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
19826 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
19916 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
19916 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
19935 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
19955 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
20509 INFO: Looking for eggs
20509 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python38.dll
20509 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
20528 INFO: Warnings written to C:\123\program\build\gui_3\warn-gui_3.txt
20690 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\123\program\build\gui_3\xref-gui_3.html
20779 INFO: checking PYZ
20779 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
20779 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\123\program\build\gui_3\PYZ-00.pyz
22685 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\123\program\build\gui_3\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
22721 INFO: checking PKG
22721 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
22721 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
22775 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
22775 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
22775 INFO: checking EXE
22775 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
22775 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
22775 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
22793 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
22793 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
22810 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\123\program\build\gui_3\gui_3.exe
24034 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
24034 INFO: checking COLLECT
24034 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
24034 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
26318 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Посмотрите, кто есть `sys.executable` в скомпилированном варианте. Подозреваю, что он будет указывать на ваш скомпилированный exe, а не на python. Я не компилировал ни разу, так что не знаю, можно ли как-то достучаться до вкомпиленного python. Как вариант, можно попробовать научить ваш gui_3.py запускать переданный в качестве аргумента скрипт вместо исполнения себя самого, как бы поработав интерпретатором питона.

Comment: @GrAnd действительно, проблема в том, что sys.executable считает мой скрипт компилятором. Не придумал ничего умнее чем вручную прописать путь до интерпретатора вместо использования функции sys.executable. Возможно кто-то предложит более изящный вариант решения...